# Changing the color of Dimple.js tooltip helper lines

Tags: colors, tooltip, bar-chart, helper, dimple.js

I am plotting a standard bar chart using dimple.js and am able to change the color of the tooltip box and the bars but the x,y helper lines that pop-up when you mouseover a bar remain the original color and I can't figure out how to change them.

Comment: can you put an example on JSBin or other service of how you're currently setting up the chart and changing the colors?

Comment: Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/CatherineRichards/xbL6pns8/9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a tricky problem because it's not well supported by Dimple. There isn't a class applied to those lines so you can't target them with a classname for css (the other tooltip objects do have a classname, but the line element is separate from those). Here's what the tooltip HTML looks like, for reference :

[image: tooltip markup]

That first `<line>` element is what we want. I found two options that work but are hackish.

1) Use CSS to target the lines - the tooltip is added as a `<g>` group after everything else in the svg, so you can look for the first line element(s) in that group:

```
svg > g:last-of-type > line {
  stroke:  lightgrey !important;
      opacity: 0.55 !important;
}
```

This only works for your particular use case of changing the line for every element - it isn't dependent on the color of the bars, if they were different.

2) The lines originally get their color by looking at the `fill` attribute of the bar - which is still whatever it was originally set to even if you mask it later with css. So one thing you can do is override the original color (since you will mask it later anyway).

```
myChart.addSeries("Cancer", dimple.plot.bar);
myChart.defaultColors = [
  new dimple.color("lightgrey")
];
```

Other than that, I can't think of a way to get the lines to match colors which are only specified in css without a change in the library. (Or writing your own tooltip function).

Comment: color display same when we use multiple chart on the same page @ne8il do you have any solution